# Button with specific ID won't fire alert();

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with jQuery I am trying to use inside my container. I really can't say what is wrong but for some reason when I click on **Button1** nothing is alerted. When I click on other buttons it is. Because the code is same for all of them I wonder why it is not working.

Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Button2").click(function () {
            alert("hi");
        });
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            alert("hello");
        });
        $("#<%=Button3.ClientID%>").click(function() {
            alert("sometext");
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" />
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="BU" />
```

When I change its ID and selector from "Button1" to "Button21" it works... What did I do wrong?

//No errors in console.

Comment: You don't accidentally have duplicate IDs in your html somewhere?

Comment: You better change the ID then..You might have duplicated used somewhere

Comment: You are right. Master page contains same id. Shame on me. :/